# User rating on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I'm a newbie in MongoDB and I'm trying to understand how to create objects there and how to select them in comparison with relational databases. So I need an example how to perform these things.

Let's say, I have two tables for now in MySQL:

```
user:

user_id INT <- PK
first_name VARCHAR(35)
last_name VARCHAR(35)
email VARCHAR(254)
```

and

```
user_rating:

rating_id INT <- PK
value FLOAT
time TIMESTAMP
```

I need to select two things:

> 1) N best users sorted by rating (ORDER BY)
>
> 2) get the current user's rating by his/her user_id.

How to create these entities in MongoDB and how to select this information from them?

Thank you for help!

Comment: Does each user have just one rating? Your requirements make me think so, but I want to confirm.

Comment: Yes, they have only a rating + information about users in user's table.

Answer (score 0):

Since each user has exactly one rating, just store the rating with the user:

```
{
    "user_id" : 0,
    "first_name" : "Jacob",
    "last_name" : "Welsh",
    "email" : "fake23@fake.com",
    "rating" : {
        "value" : 9001,
        "time" : ISODate("2015-02-26T20:28:54.153Z")
    }
}
```

> N best users sorted by rating (ORDER BY)

```
db.users.find({ }).sort({ "rating" : -1 }).limit(N)
```

assuming higher rating is better

> get the current user's rating by his/her user_id.

```
db.users.find({ "user_id" : user_id }, { "_id" : 0, "rating" : 1 })
```